# In Corda, what's the difference between well-known, service and confidential identities?

Tags: corda

In Corda, could you please explain the difference between:

- A well-known identity
- A service identity
- A confidential identity

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- A well-known identity is the identity that a node publicises to the network via the network map
- A service identity is an identity that is shared across all the nodes in a notary cluster, allowing the cluster to be addressed as a single logical unit
- A confidential identity is a pseudonymous identity that is generated for a specific transaction or set of transactions, in order to not reveal a node’s involvement in the transaction